# Play framework plugin does not execute serveStatic when launched by IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

I have a small play project which uses the [sass module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/sass), which includes a plugin that hooks in to the `serverStatic()` process. It works as expected when I start play using `play run`. However, when I start play "directly" as as a Java process from Intellij, the `serverStatic()` method is never executed. Everything else seems to work as expected.

I configured IntelliJ following the "[Setting up your IDE](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/ide#intellij)" part documentation, including the run configuration.

Do I need some environment variables or VM options, that are maybe missing in the documentation?